# Scroll to bottom for PrimeFaces tab

Tags: java, primefaces, tabs

I have a PrimeFaces tab as below

```
 <p:tabView id="fieldPanel" widgetVar="pad"> 
 <p:tab title="tab1" id="tab1">
 <div class="xxx" id="divTab1">
 <table>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 </p:tab>
 </p:tabView>

 </form>
```

And I'm using jQuery to append  to the 'table tbody'.

After appending I would like to scroll to the bottom of the tab. I'm using the script as below

```
 var tab = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('formMainId:fieldPanel'));
 tab.scrollTop(tab.height());
```

But I don't see it scroll to the bottom. Could you please advice?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you want to scroll in the tab instead of the tabView?

Comment: I do want to scroll the tab but also not working with scroll tab